# Getting Started with SQLite PCL

Tags: sqlite, portable-class-library

All,

I am struggling to get off the ground with SQLite.  I cannot seem to find the right search terms to get the answer I need, so have come here.

I simply want to do this: have a single dll (PCL) that contains all my SQLite logic.  I have installed the NuGet package SQLitePCL from Microsoft Open Technologies into this PCL project.  I have written a single method that opens a connection.

I then have a test harness console application that references my PCL DLL project.  That, in its root, has the file SQLite3.dll, that I downloaded from the SQLite site.  Obviously, this console application calls my OpenConnection method in the library dll.

I am getting the error:

> Additional information: A SQLite Wrapper assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the current project references both SQLitePCL and the following platform-specific assembly: SQLitePCL.Ext

So my questions are:

- where do I get that platform specific assembly from?
- Is there an article on the web that specifically demonstrates how to do this?

Help gratefully appreciated,
Gray

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Your question asks to find both a library and a tutorial or off-site resource.

Comment: Not sure I agree, Ken, in the main.  My question is about a specific error I am getting while trying to use SQLite and SQLitePCL.  However, if someone wanted to spend 30 seconds telling me about an article they used to get a handle on this, then I wasn't going to complain.  That was very secondary to the first, very specific, question.

Comment: Your (two part) question: So my questions are "Where do I get that assembly from?" and "Is there an article on the web?", both of which ask where to **find a book, tool, software library, tutorial of other off-site resource". You **specifically stated** that those were your questions. In what way do you disagree with the close reason I've quoted above?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... the answer to this was painfully simple.  The platform specific assemblies are in the "packages\SQLitePCL.3.8.5.1\build" folder (put there by NuGet, of course).  I just copied the dll from the sub folder Netcore451 into the root of my console app.

Comment: netcore451 is intended for Windows Store 8.1 Apps, not Console apps. But I'm glad it's working for you. You may find [SQLitePCL.raw](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw) or [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) easier to use.

Comment: Many thanks, Bricelam.  I will definitely check out those components.